# 'QDialog' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to connect two python folder together the two files contain PYQT5 UI code both of the two files run the codes good but I'm trying to connect the two file with a `pushbutton`:
**file_1 called graph_window.py**
contains a pushbutton which when I click it will show file_2 output UI this a proportion of the code :

```
from output_graph import Dialog # file_2
  def view_graph_output(self):
        self.w = Dialog()
        self.w.show()

  def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(304, 162, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # click function for the push button
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.view_graph_output)
```

**file two called output_graph.py**

```
class Ui_Dialog:
   def setupUi(self, Dialog):
       Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
       Dialog.resize(900, 500)

       self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
       self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 380, 141, 61))
       self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
   def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "output window"))

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
       fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
       self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
       FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
       self.setParent(parent)
       self.plot()

   def plot(self):
       x = np.array([50, 30, 40])
       labels = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Melons"]
       self.axes.pie(x, labels=labels)
       self.draw()


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super().__init__(parent)
       self.setupUi(self)
       self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=8, height=4)
       self.canvas.move(0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = Dialog()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when I run the code it gives me this error:

> TypeError: 'QDialog' object is not callable

it seems I'm doing wrong when I call the output_graph from the `Dialog` class and I try to put the `QtWidgets.QDialog` with the calls and it didn't work

is there a way to call the dialog class from the pushbutton form file_1?

Comment: I'm a little confused about your code because you have a class named `Dialog` but it also appears you're using a local variable named `Dialog` which I guess refers to an *instance* of the `Dialog` *class*?  This shouldn't be a problem in general since the local variable will shadow the global variable referring to the class, but it makes it hard to tell exactly what your intent is.  When posting questions about errors in Python code it's more useful if you post the *full traceback* leading up to the error, because that will help pinpoint exactly where in your code it's coming from.

Comment: I think I see now you are passing a `Dialog` instance as the callback for a push button.  But what are you expecting that to do?  If you want it to show the dialog you would pass `Dialog.show`.

Comment: @Iguananaut I will make sure in the future question to put the full traceback,
about passing the dialog is `self.w.show()` do the same as `Dialog.show` ?

Comment: @Iguananaut that "Dialog" is part of what's generated by a PyQt tool, pyuic, which gets an XML file (containing the UI structure) as input. The program that generates those ui files starts by creating a main widget container which has an upper cased name by default (Dialog, Form, MainWindow) and the pyuic tool recreates the python file using that name. I agree that it's a bit of an unfortunate choice (but I believe it's derived from what the Qt equivalent C++ oriented tool does) especially from the python styling point of view, and that's also often source of confusion to new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should go like this:

```
import sys

from output_graph import Dialog  # file_2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()
        # self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=8, height=4)
        # self.canvas.move(0, 0)

    def view_graph_output(self):
        self.w = Dialog()
        self.w.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('push', self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(304, 162, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # click function for the push button
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.view_graph_output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui_Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and output_graph.py should be:

```
import sys
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import numpy as np

class Ui_Dialog:
   def setupUi(self, Dialog):
       Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
       Dialog.resize(900, 500)

       self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
       self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 380, 141, 61))
       self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
       # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: funcion(12))
   def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "output window"))

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
       fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
       self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
       FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
       self.setParent(parent)
       self.plot()

   def plot(self):
       x = np.array([50, 30, 40])
       labels = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Melons"]
       self.axes.pie(x, labels=labels)
       self.draw()


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super().__init__(parent)
       self.setupUi(self)
       self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=8, height=4)
       self.canvas.move(0, 0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = Dialog()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PS: it's a messy code so requires cleaning up, but works as you wanted, as to my understanding of the problem**

Comment: thank you you helped me a lot it seems that I need to understand more about the difference between sending Dialog and self thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure, keep it up!